# NavigationController for only 1 level of navigation - is it good practice?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have `TabViewController` with 3 tabs: t1, t2, t3 and only tab t3 will have a tableview where when you click on one cell, a new view controller will load but that viewcontroller does not have a back button.

I can add a Navigation controller between the TabViewController -> t3 -> NavigationController -> ViewController but Is there any other way? I can add a navigation bar to it and add a back button functionality.

Is this good practice to add a navigation controller even though you need 1 level of navigation?

Comment: In general... don't think about the technical aspect - think about the User aspect. Will it confuse the user to see a "standard" `table -> tap row -> new view slides in` but there is no "< Back" navigation? If so, you should probably use a nav controller. If not, then you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is You can't do navigation without navigation controller. Doesn't matter whether l level or more levels.

As @DonMag says it's User aspect if you wanna navigate while tapping rows then of course you should use navigation controller with back if you need.else you present viewController simply.